# seq with a constant r

Tags: r, seq

I'm looking to create a seq with a constant part. Something like this:
GBR1
GBR2
.
.
.
GBR50000

I tried to do it with the seq function but I was not successful. Does anyone know how to easily do the trick?

Comment: Things like this are covered in the [Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Character-vectors) manual. You might want to review that if you are new to R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
paste("GBR",1:50000,sep = "")
```

or

```
sprintf("GBR%d", 1:5e5)
```

Comment: I think a good answer should explain to the OP why seq can't do the job, but don't want to figure out how to write it. Also, I don't want to crowd out answers from newer users. Also, mine is a pretty trivial variation on the paste/paste0 way.

Comment: To include `seq`, you could do `paste("GBR", seq(1, 50000), sep="")` or better still `paste("GBR", seq_len(50000), sep="")`.

Answer (score 2):

```
paste0("GBR",1:10)
 [1] "GBR1"  "GBR2"  "GBR3"  "GBR4"  "GBR5"  "GBR6"  "GBR7"  "GBR8"  "GBR9"  "GBR10"
```